# Moving windows store apps to another PC windows 10

Tags: microsoft-store, windows-10-apps

I have a computer that does not have internet access and I am looking for a way to download apps from Microsoft store on another device and then move them to that PC.
I cannot find a way that works.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There isn't. You need to be online.

Comment: You actually CAN install applications from the Windows Store while offline.  You have to download the package, in order to do so, it's a simple command.  You would install such a package with `Add-AppxPackage .\typeexactfilenamehere.appxbundle`. You can use something like [this](https://store.rg-adguard.net/) to find and download the appx bundle.  I can write a full answer when I have a machine to test commands out on

Comment: You can try to manually download the app move it to the PC and there install it. Not sure if this still works:  https://www.ghacks.net/2018/07/18/how-to-download-microsoft-store-apps/

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achieved.

It requires first installing the [Microsoft Application Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/app-installer/9nblggh4nns1?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), which ironically requires you to be connected to the internet, but there is a solution to that problem.

You can download the application bundle file then run the command below in an elevated PowerShell prompt.

```
Add-AppxPackage .\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_2019.1019.1.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe.appxbundle
```

You can achieve that by using https://store.rg-adguard.net/ to download the Microsoft Application Installer which will then allow you to download other Application Bundles and simply double click them like an installer.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer just that I ham having a hard time because each app has different dependencies (e.g., different versions of native. Runtime) Is there any way to figure out which dependicies an appx bundle needs without installing it?

Comment: @jakeOleal - Which dependencies exactly?